# Smice Custom printer & Openbravo pos

Tags: printing, serial-port, receipt, javapos, openbravo

I have a Custom printer Smice and I can not run with the software with Openbravo POS.

I connected the printer via serial port but when I try to print a receipt, the printer printing unreadable characters.
I've tried all combinations of printers / methods (serial, file) but no one worked.

On the site of custom there aren't driver or info about the printer. I also tried with JavaPOS, through the tester 1.10 but I have always errors (Could not create the service istance).

Someone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you are seeing a mismatched baud rate. You should make certain that the baud rate on the printer is matched to the baud rate you've setup in OpenBravo.

Comment: I'm not sure - after looking on the OpenBravo website it doesn't look like there is an easy configuration option. I know a little bit about POS and the printer connections but I've never used OpenBravo. I found this link:

http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Projects:POS/Hardware_Installation_Guide

Looks like it might use 9600?

Comment: i set the com port on windows at 9600 bps. I think that this printer is too old for this POS and on web there aren't guide or doc...

Comment: Not sure - it might be beneficial to check the support on try asking your question on the OpenBravo forums as well.

Comment: i've ask my question on the custom customer center and they sended me the driver for windows xp, vista and seven. But nothing changed. 
I haven't the printer now and i will change it with epson or ibm, i think.

Thanks anyway!